# Pass data to a function untill array length

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

So I have a function that takes multiple arrays as arguments but the data I have is already in an array **(say mainArr)**. so **mainArr** is an array that contains multiple array items that I need to put them in the function arguments.
here's the code:

```
// NOTE: YOU DON'T NEED TO UNDERSTAND THIS FUNCTION

function getCombinations(...args) {
        let r = [], max = args.length - 1;
        function helper(arr, i) {
            for (let j = 0; j < args[i].length; j++) {
                let a = arr.slice(0); // clone arr
                a.push(args[i][j].value);
                if (i === max) {
                    r.push(a);
                } else {
                    helper(a, i + 1);
                }
            }
        }
        helper([], 0);
        return r;
    }
```

I want something like this:

```
const mainArr = [
            {
                values: [
                    { value: 1 },
                    { value: 2 }
                ]
            }, {
                values: [
                    { value: 2 },
                    { value: 1 }
                ]
            }
        ]

getCombinations(mainArr[0].values, mainArr[1].values)
```

actually, I want to get the combinations of arrays and the function I made to get the combination, takes multiple arrays as arguments. for example, if I want to get the combination of two arrays, it takes two arrays as two different arguments. but the data I have is inside another array so I just want to strip the arrays from that single array.

Comment: *"but I want to automatically fill indexes of the array dynamically"* ? Could you clarify? What's the input? What should be the output?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but if you want to pull out the `values` arrays and then pass each of those as separate arguments, this might be kind of what you're looking for: `getCombinations(...mainArr.map(v => v.values));`

Comment: actually, I want to get the combinations of arrays and the function I made to get the combination, takes multiple arrays as arguments. for example, if I want to get the combination of two arrays, it takes two arrays as two different arguments. but the data I have is inside another array so I just want to strip the arrays from that single array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the parameter of function `getCombinations` an array.

```js
function getCombinations(args) {
  let r = [], max = args.length - 1;
  function helper(arr, i) {
    for (let j = 0; j < args[i].length; j++) {
      let a = arr.slice(0); // clone arr
      a.push(args[i][j].value);
      if (i === max) {
        r.push(a);
      } else {
        helper(a, i + 1);
      }
    }
  }
  helper([], 0);
  return r;
}
const mainArr = [
  {
    values: [
      { value: 1 },
      { value: 2 }
    ]
  }, {
    values: [
      { value: 2 },
      { value: 1 }
    ]
  }
]

const x = getCombinations([mainArr[0].values, mainArr[1].values]);
console.log(x);
const list = mainArr.map(node => node.values);
const y = getCombinations(list);
console.log(y);
```

Comment: So basically the map is returning the array with values and the function is processing the array. Nice. Thanx bro